# Firebase Performance not showing requests made to Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-performance

I installed the Firebase Performance SDK and was surprised by the success rate I was getting. I went into more detail only to see that the calls listed on the "Network Request" tab are all of different requests such as Crashlytics and other custom ones, but nothing related to the performance of my Cloud Firestore requests.

Are these requests meant to show up there, or am I using FP wrong? Is there any other way to see the success rate and performance of my Cloud Firestore Database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Performance Monitoring only picks up HTTP requests automatically.  It doesn't know anything about Firestore requests, because they don't go over an HTTP connection using an API that it knows about.

If you want to measure Firestore performance from using Firebase Perf, you'll have to write code for that, either with traces or the manual HTTP .  You can use the [manual network request API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/perf/FirebasePerformance.html#newHttpMetric(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).  The API is not well documented right now, but it lets you write code that creates HTTP metrics in the dashboard according to your own measurements.